# How do I schedule an AppPool refresh for an Azure Web-App service?

Tags: azure, sitecore8, azure-web-app-service

We have a website running as a web-app service on Azure.  Our CM environment stalls and needs restarted periodically.

While we investigate the cause of this, I'd like to set the application pool to refresh overnight.  I can't find anything in the portal to indicate how or where this is done.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kudu service allows you to setup auto healing based on rules for memory, requests, or status code. To get to the dashboard navigate to `https://[Your Azure App Name].scm.azurewebsites.net` and then click on `Tools -> Support` and then turn on `Autoheal`, click `Update` and then optionally add any rules that make sense.

For more details, check out the blog post [Auto Heal your Azure Web App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2015/11/04/auto-heal-your-azure-web-app/).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a webjob to your service where you can upload a zipped .bat file and schedule it to run using a cron job

I THINK something like this should do it

```
azure webapp restart --resource-group xxx --name xxx
```

But, don't really want to mess about too much with our live environment.

The Kudu solution looks like the one we are going to go with.  But, not until we take a good look at the perfomance/analytics.  We definitely have a memory leak on the go somewhere