# Is it possible to recycle app pool for a Azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to recycle app pool for websites hosted in Azure Web app. Usually website hosted on a vm or as a web role we could create a powershell script which creates ps session and recycle the app pool. Is there a similar approach we can use for Azure Web app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I schedule an AppPool refresh for an Azure Web-App service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672506/how-do-i-schedule-an-apppool-refresh-for-an-azure-web-app-service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azurermps-5.1.1) to manage Azure web apps. In your case [`Restart-AzureRmWebApp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/restart-azurermwebapp?view=azurermps-5.1.1) is the cmdlet you want to use.

The typical way to do this is to first sign in to Azure and then execute PowerShell commands:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
# Only required if you need to select a specific subscription
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionName "MySubscriptionName"
Restart-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "Default-Web-WestUS" -Name "ContosoSite"
```

Comment: Does this recycle the AppPool or does  it perform an IIS reset? It seems like the latter in testing.

Answer (score 6):

Using the Kudo console / editor you can edit the web.config file to include a comment such as the one below.

> <-- Test -->

After saving this file the AppPool should recycle.

In testing this brings the application much faster than restarting the webapp through the Azure portal.

Comment: Also, you can double confirm this via Kudu -> Process Explorer -> w3wp.exe's  pid should change to a new number too.